# How to convert variable from the type 'string' to the type 'views' in Django?

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
def handbook_cpu_add(request):
    ...
```

models.py:

```
class CPU(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

test.py:

```
def test_add_comparison_url(self):
    helper.handbook_add_comparison_url(self, 'cpu')
```

helper.py:

```
def handbook_add_comparison_url(self, item):
    found = resolve('/hardware/handbook/' + item + '/add/')
    t = 'handbook_' + item + '_add'

    self.assertEqual(found.func, t)
```

How to convert variable 't' from the type 'string' to the type 'handbook_cpu_add'?

Comment: This is not something you would do. Why are you doing it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have many models and different tests and I want to reduce amount of code in these tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about this backwards. You don't need to convert the string to a function or a view, all you need to do is get the name from the function and compare that to your string:

```
self.assertEqual(found.func.__name__, t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your original question, [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) is what you are looking for:

```
import views


view = getattr(views, 'name')
```

However, consider using @Duncan's answer for this kind of purposes.